# get value for each row on DB table

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, datatables

I have this Jquery code that is supposed to give me the result of a column if I click on it's row. I'm using Yii but the problem is mostly with the Jquery.

```
$(document).on('click', 'td.myLink a', function(){
    $('input[name=\"ECCategory[ParentID]\"]').val($('#mainID').html());

        $('.search-form form').submit();
});
```

This is what I have. What this does is gives me the result of the first row (mainID column) no matter which row I click on. What I want for example is to click on row 5 and get the mainID for row 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are unique. So only one element can have the id `mainID`. You probably want to use `$(this)` within your [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event to search from the selected element. For example:

```
$(function($){
    $('td.myLink a').click(function(){
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent(); // selected row
        // get columns that you want from selected row using tr.find('...')
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nicely said, thank you. Just wondering why are we doing this  var tr = $(this).parent().parent(); ...... What does parent().parent() exactly do here?

Comment: No worries. `$(this)` is the jQuery Object for `a`. Calling `parent()` gets its parent which is the `td` object. Calling it again gives the parent of `td` which is `tr`- the row

Comment: Fantastic I will keep that in mind from now on. Appreciate it.